# Hide/show controls in uninstall process in Wix Toolset

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation

I have created a WiX installer and would like to hide or show a control in last screen when user finish uninstall or install process.

```
<Control Id="cbxOpenURL" Type="CheckBox" X="135" Y="160" Width="10" Height="10" Property="OPENURLONEXIT" CheckBoxValue="1">
       <Condition Action="hide">REMOVE</Condition>
       <Condition Action="show">NOT REMOVE</Condition>
</Control>

<Control Id="txtOpenURL" Type="Text" X="150" Y="160" Width="160" Height="20" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="!(loc.ExitDlgOpenurlCheck)" >
              <Condition Action="hide">REMOVE</Condition>
              <Condition Action="show">NOT REMOVE</Condition>
            </Control>
```

It does not work. What I am doing wrong??

Comment: I ran a quick test, and for some strange reason it seems a number of properties are flushed before this dialog appears. I am not sure why - maybe the WiX guys can explain. There might be some hacky ways to get this working - for example by using the registry, but I am not sure how important this feature is for you.

Comment: During testing I thought I saw it working when the condition was REMOVE=ALL, but that makes no sense. It must have been a glitch. Just mentioning it in case you want to try it to be sure. I don't have time for more testing.

Answer (score 0):

The REMOVE property isn't set until after the InstallValidate action, and that is after the UI dialogs.

The install and uninstall dialog sequences are usually separate (based on each Next value from the starting dialog) so this type of issue doesn't arise when the dialog flows are unique. The sequences typically start based on the Installed property, starting with a Maintenance type of dialog when Installed is set, and with a Welcome type of dialog when Installed is not set, each having their own dialog sequence.

Comment: Astonishingly it seems to me like the **`REMOVE`** property value does not get returned to the UI sequence after the install sequence has completed.  I tested with another tool than WiX though. I was able to get a number of other properties in this state of the install though: `ALLUSERS`, `package-`, `product-` & `upgrade GUIDs`, `UILevel`, `Privileged`, `INSTALLLEVEL`... So there is a **`Session object`**, it just doesn't report anything for **`REMOVE`**. So it seemed during my ad-hoc testing.

Comment: I started wondering if this could be related to major upgrade behavior - some properties needing to be reset - but a major upgrade involves a whole new session object so that makes no sense?